# Removing equivalent authors in a list

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, graph

I have a list of authors, where seeking duplicity. The indexes of these duplicates are stored in a list of lists named duplicity. For example, at index 0 in the list duplicity is nested list, which refer to indexes of authors list with duplicates author A, index 1 author duplicity B, etc.
I also have list edge, where indexes of nodes(authors) are stored that are connected by an edge. Program passes through and removes duplicate authors by list duplicity.

For example I have stored in duplicity list indexes 1, 2, 3. These refers to authors list, where are stored names of authors. It also refers to edge list, where are stored start and end point of edges. For example if I have authors stored on indexes 1,2,3 and they are connected altogether, than the edge list is 1,2, 1,3, 2,3. Because authors on indexes 1,2,3 are same, I need make them one. So I pass edge list and replace all 2 and 3 to 1.

**The problem is that progress of code below is very slow.** I'm sure that in the code is something useless which raise complexity, but I can not figure it out. **I think, the main failure in my code is the first part with the for loops. It many times passes authors list and if there are tens of thousands items, it's really slow.** Can you help me optimize this code?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < authors.GetDuplicates().Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < edge.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < authors.GetDuplicates()[i].Count - 1; k++)
                {
                    if (edge[j] == authors.GetDuplicates()[i].ElementAt(k))
                    {
                        edge[j] = authors.GetDuplicates()[i].ElementAt(k + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

 public static List<List<int>> GetDuplicates(this IList<string> source)
    {
        HashSet<string> itemsSeen = new HashSet<string>();
        HashSet<string> itemsYielded = new HashSet<string>();
        List<List<int>> duplicates = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> dupLow = new List<int>();
        HashSet<int> temp = new HashSet<int>();

        int c = 0;

        foreach (string item in source)
        {
            if (!itemsSeen.Add(item))
            {
                if (itemsYielded.Add(item))
                {
                    if (item != "-")
                    {
                        int w = 0;

                        for (int j = 0; j < authors.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if (authors[j] == authors[c])
                            {
                                temp.Add(w);
                            }
                            w++;
                        }

                        dupLow = new List<int>(temp);
                        duplicates.Add(dupLow);
                        temp.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }
            c++;
        }
        return duplicates;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
We have four authors, A and B are authors of one book and C and A are authors of different book. Authors within one book are connected by edge. We can see, there are two authors "A". So we replace in edges index of author A (index 0) to 3. At the end books are connected by common author.

authors | edge | remove dup. | bad result 
[0] A    [0] 0   [0] 3    [0] 4
[1] B    [1] 1   [1] 1    [1] 1

[2] C    [2] 2   [2] 2    [2] 2
[3] A    [3] 3   [3] 3    [3] 3

The result should look like this:

[image: The result should look like this:]

Comment: please post a follow up question to this when you have a new version, we would love to see it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I follow the code, but I would try removing the repeated calls to `GetDuplicates`:

```
foreach (var duplicate in authors.GetDuplicates())
{
    for (int j = 0; j < edge.Count; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < duplicate.Count - 1; k++)
        {
            if (edge[j] == duplicate[k])
            {
                edge[j] = duplicate[k + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've also replaced the calls to `ElementAt` with use of the indexer, as I think it's clearer.

Comment: This is faster, but gives me wrong result. In duplicate list, I store data in list of lists, so therefore I used authors.GetDuplicates()[i].ElementAt(k) , where "i" refers to upper list and "k" to nested list.

Comment: @Tomas can you please provide an example of `authors`, `edge`, and the expected result where this gives the wrong answer? I'm confused since on the `i`th iteration, `duplicate[k]` should be equal to `authors.GetDuplicates()[i].ElementAt(k)`. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, a just must deal with text formatting to make it clear.

Comment: @Tomas you could post the example on [ideone](http://ideone.com/) if that makes it easier.

Comment: Edited first post.

Comment: @Tomas thanks for posting the example. I'm getting a result of 3, 1, 2, 3 as expected. You can see the code running at [this link](http://ideone.com/TqtF8T), output is at the bottom of the page. `GetDuplicates` is copy-pasted from the question.

Comment: I found a mistake. Banality, as usual. At beginning, in list of authors every book is separated by "-". So the list is A, B, -, C, A, - . I need this dashes, when I create edge list first time. I accidentally comment out the function, that remove these dashes. Also in GetDuplicates function condidion if (item != "-") is useless. Now it's work much better and faster. Thank you very much for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2):

This little bit of code

> ```
>         if (!itemsSeen.Add(item))
>         {
>             if (itemsYielded.Add(item))
>             {
>                 if (item != "-")
>                 {
> ```

can be simplified into

```
if (!itemsSeen.Add(item) && itemsYielded.Add(item) && item != "-")
{
```

---

I am not sure I follow exactly how the code works, but I think you could benefit from using `List<>`'s built in `Contains()` method.  Check it out [MSDN  `List(T).Contains` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)

You should be able to get rid of the `k` for loop by using the `Contains()` Method

Comment: Thank you, that I certainly can change. I think, the main failure in my code is the first part with the for loops. It several times passes authors list and if there are tens of thousands items, it's really slow.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < authors.GetDuplicates().Count; i++)
> {
>     for (int j = 0; j < edge.Count; j++)
>     {
>         for (int k = 0; k < authors.GetDuplicates()[i].Count - 1; k++)
>         {
>             if (edge[j] == authors.GetDuplicates()[i].ElementAt(k))
>             {
>                 edge[j] = authors.GetDuplicates()[i].ElementAt(k + 1);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

What are you doing here ? You are calling `GetDuplicates()` on almost every line of code.

Assuming `authors.GetDuplicates().Count == 3` with each containing list having `Count == 2` and `edge.Count == 3` you will for the best case call `authors.GetDuplicates()` 28 times , where one time is enough.

```
var duplicates = authors.GetDuplicates()
for (int i = 0; i < duplicates.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < edge.Count; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < duplicates[i].Count - 1; k++)
        {
            if (edge[j] == duplicates[i].ElementAt(k))
            {
                edge[j] = duplicates[i].ElementAt(k + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the problem now. You are right in yours assumptions. I edited the code and now it's work better. Thank you.